# C# Alternating numbers, more effective way of achieving same result?

Tags: c#

Alright so i have this functional code here, and am wondering if there is a better way, as in more concise or functional way of doing the same thing?

the expected output would be something like: 1, -1, 2, -2 ...

I believe the use of the " int x" could be removed or put within the loop for a local variable, perhaps someone could show me how that would be?

```
namespace AlternatingPosNegNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[100];
            int[] numbPos = new int[100];
            int[] numbNeg = new int[100];
            int x = 0;

            for (int i =numbers[x]; i <numbers.Length; i++, x++)
            {
                numbPos[i] = i;
                numbNeg[i] = i - (i * 2);

                Console.WriteLine(numbPos[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(numbNeg[i]);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `numbers` for? Are you expecting to prepopulate this with values you want to be made positive and negative? or are you in fact always wanting to generate that same sequence (ie starting from `1,-1...`)?

Comment: Is it just for printing? If so why hold arrays? for-loop from 1 to 100 and print once in positive and once in negative (by multiplying by -1 or just printing a '-' before the number. Also why `i - (i * 2)` just `-i`

Comment: You can figure it out as long as you get started right.  Get rid of `numbers` and use a `List<int>` for the result.

Comment: Why not just -i?  You don't even use x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a better way, as in more concise...

```
int[] result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).SelectMany(i => new[] {i, -i}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a formula that gives you the sequence you want like this

```
   for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        int y = (x + 1) / 2 * (x % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
```